# Receiving multiple Adaptive card when used a timer in .net bot framework sdk v4

Tags: .net, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have created simple reminder functionality in the teams bot channel using bot framework sdk v4.
the reminder are stored in sharepoint and retrieved at the time of the scheduled time, for which i m using a timer function. the functionality works fine when the reminder are set at different time we recieve single adaptive card for each reminder. but when we create n reminders scheduled at the same time ,I m getting n*n cards which is not the correct functionality.
how can we stop this behavior and get only a single card for each reminder when scheduled at same time.

here is the code which is responsible for timer and sending the card to user from bot.

````
private async Task SetReminderTimer(ITurnContext turnContext, ReminderListDto reminderTask, DateTime dateTime, string userInputTimeZoneOffset)
        {
            try
            {
                // Calculate the time until the reminder should trigger
                var delay = dateTime - DateTime.Now;

                _reminderTimer = new Timer(async _ =>
                {
                    // Retrieve the reminder item from SharePoint
                    var reminders = await _sharePointLogger.GetReminderFromSharePointAsync(reminderTask, userInputTimeZoneOffset);

                    foreach (var reminder in reminders)
                    {
                        // If the reminder item exists and the reminder time is in the past, send the reminder message to the user
                        if (reminder != null && DateTime.Now > reminderTask.Time)
                        {
                            // Send a reminder message to the user
                            var conversationReference = turnContext.Activity.GetConversationReference();
                            await ((BotAdapter)turnContext.Adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_botId, conversationReference, async (turnContext, cancellationToken) =>
                            {
                                var displayReminder = ReminderList.DisplayReminder(reminder.Time.ToString("HH:mm"), reminder.ReminderType, reminder.Priority, reminder.ReminderDetails);
                                var adaptiveCardAttachment = new Attachment()
                                {
                                    ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                                    Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(displayReminder),
                                };
                                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Attachment(adaptiveCardAttachment), cancellationToken);
                            }, default);
                            //await DeleteReminderFromSharePointAsync(reminder.ReminderId);

                        }
                    }

                }, null, (int)delay.TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation($"error at sedning reminder to user {ex.Message} ");
                throw;
            }

        }
```cs

I have tried adding a dictionary and set the reminderId as the key and check if the key is present already then dont send duplicate card for that reminder.. but its not working.

can we get some solution to prevent multiple cards to be sent for single reminder
````

Comment: While debugging i found that each statement in foreach loop executes multiple time before executing the next statement in foreach loop. hence the below answer provided wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are getting multiple adaptive cards for each reminder when they are scheduled at the same time.

- To stop this behaviour is by using a flag to check if the card has already been sent for a particular reminder.
- And set this flag to false when you retrieve the reminders from SharePoint and then set it to true when you send the adaptive card for that reminder.

C# code

```
var reminders = await _sharePointLogger.GetReminderFromSharePointAsync(reminderTask, userInputTimeZoneOffset);

foreach (var rem in reminders)
{
    if (rem != null && DateTime.Now > reminderTask.Time)
    {
        if (!rem.CardSent)
        {
            var conversationReference = turnContext.Activity.GetConversationReference();
            await ((BotAdapter)turnContext.Adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_botId, conversationReference, async (turnContext, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                var display_Reminder = ReminderList.DisplayReminder(reminder.Time.ToString("HH:mm"), reminder.ReminderType, reminder.Priority, reminder.ReminderDetails);
                var adaptiveCardAttachment = new Attachment()
                {
                    ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                    Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(display_Reminder),
                };

                var activity = MessageFactory.Attachment(adaptiveCardAttachment);
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activity, cancellationToken);

                reminder.CardSent = true;
                await _sharePointLogger.UpdateReminderInSharePointAsync(reminderTask, reminder);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And the configuration setup

[image]

**ListOfAccounts and Actions**

[image]

For more information, refer to [MSDoc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-adaptive-cards?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) and [MSDoc2.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General/How-to-create-an-adaptive-Card-for-Multiple-options/td-p/1798032)

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).